# Calling method of another enum inside enum

Tags: java, enums

I have a Java enum class which is defined as follows :

```
public enum FTSF implements ME<FTSF>, SF {

  ID(DSF.ID.getCode(), "T Id", DSF.ID.getColumnName()),
  CURRENT_TS(DSF.CURRENT_TS.getCode(),
             DSF.CURRENT_TS.getDescription(),
             DSF.CURRENT_TS.getColumnName()),;
```

The DSF enum class is defined as follows :

```
public enum DSF implements ME<DSF>, SF {

  ID("Id", "Id", "externalId"),
  CURRENT_TS("CurrentTs", "Current Timestamp", "currentTs"),;

  // There are getCode(), getDescription() and getColumnName() methods defined in this class and so on ....
```

;

I am slightly confused with the type of declaration of `CURRENT_TS` is used in `FTSF` class. So, basically, as mentioned in the `FTSF` class, the `CURRENT_TS` enum declaration contains `DSF.CURRENT_TS.getCode()` etc. So, if I understood, correctly, the `FTSF` class(for CURRENT_TS) is taking the first value(`Current_Ts`) from the following declaration which is mentioned in `DSF` class?

`CURRENT_TS("CurrentTs", "Current Timestamp", "currentTs"),;`

Comment: Have you tried? It's easy to write a simple main function to see what is inside the first field in FTSF.CURRENT_TS. (The answer is "Yes, you're right" but I think you should be able to figure that out just by running a small little program)

Comment: I am almost certain that CURRENT_TS is a different enum altogether. It has a method called getCode() which returns a string or such. DSF.CURRENT_TS is an enum and getCode() will return a string which can be used to define another CURRENT_TS enum inside FTSF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the method `getCode` of `DFS` enum return the first parameter of the enum constructor, then is correct your afirmation:

> So, if I understood, correctly, the FTSF class(for CURRENT_TS) is taking the first value(Current_Ts) from the following declaration which is mentioned in DSF class?